# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist - oracle 11g exception

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying a oracle 11g connection with eclipse and my program lists the contents of a table,
 The code that i wrote for that is

```
try { 
String connection ="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
String user ="testuser";
String password = "12345";

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");           
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connection,user,password);             stmt = con.createStatement();           
rs=stmt.executeQuery("Select * from DETAILS");      
} catch (Exception e) {             
            e.printStackTrace();        
}
```

But when i executed this , i am getting table doesnt exist exception, i am sure that i have created the table under the schema 'XE' but i am not sure what is the problem.

This is my stack trace

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CStatement.java:852)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1153)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeQuery(OracleStatement.java:1477)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OracleStatementWrapper.java:392)
    at JDBC.main(JDBC.java:20)
```

Comment: The database is also sure that there is no such table. One of you needs to check again. Missing permissions maybe?

Comment: could you please tell me how do i check it.

Comment: @Dhirish Consult your dba if there is any table named `DETAILS` in any schema. If one exists which you desired, ask him/her to be granted to schema `test`, and use with `thatschema.DETAILS` syntax.

Comment: Run `SQLPLUS` and login as `testuser` using password `12345` to the database. Then run `DESC DETAILS` command, it will tell you whether the table `details` exists or not. If the table  does not exist, then an error message will appear, otherwise the command will display a structure of the table.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan i tried the root user and i used the schema name , it worked, thank you